# How to strip devenv of all the packages unnecessary for a command line build of a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

We are using devenv command line to build our solution during the gated check-in build. Basically, it is **devenv abc.sln /build Debug**.

Now I thought to myself "devenv loads an awful lot of packages unnecessary for the build, which slows it down. Let me run it in the safe mode".

So, I modified the command line to **devenv abc.sln /build Debug /SafeMode**. And it works great, only there is one project which it fails to load. It is Portable Class Library.

Please, observe:

```
D:\TFS\DFGatedCheckIn>devenv DataSvc.sln /upgrade

Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.30723.0.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

Information:
This project/solution does not require migration. It will open without modification.

D:\TFS\DFGatedCheckIn>devenv DataSvc.sln /upgrade /safemode

Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.30723.0.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

Some errors occurred during migration. For more information, see the migration report:
D:\TFS\DFGatedCheckIn\UpgradeLog48.htm

Information:
This project/solution does not require migration. It will open without modification.

D:\TFS\DFGatedCheckIn>
```

And the only error found in the created upgrade log is:

```
Services\Platform\Resources\DfResources.csproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB
```

This one is the only Portable Class Library in our solution. So, I guess Visual Studio in the safe mode does not load the package responsible for understanding such projects.

I still want to minimize the amount of packages loaded by the Visual Studio, but not at the expense of correctness. So, my question is what is the right way to do it?

Specifically in my case - how can I run in the Safe Mode plus the package for recognizing the Portable Class Library (BTW, I do not know which one)?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. Not sure what and how this was caused. However running the command "devenv /resetuserdata general" solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar migration errors when trying to build from a VS2013 command prompt after installing VS2017 (Windows 7).  My solution was already built, so there should have been no errors.  The migration errors seem to somehow be related to .NET changes.  What fixed it for me was deleting the ComponentModelCache folder in C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 (or whatever version you're having trouble with) after closing all open instances of Visual Studio.  There "should" be no issue in deleting the folder, as it gets recreated upon re-opening VS.

Issues with the ComponentModelCache folder can apparently cause a number of odd problems: http://withmartin.net/how-visual-studios-component-model-cache-can-be-a-pain/

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**
Execute below command

`"%VS2017_Path%\devenv.com" /ResetSettings
"%VS2017_Path%\devenv.com" /setup`

**Explanation**

Ok, so I witnessed this problem today in our build server where we set up the build for the SSIS packages. All of sudden our SSIS build stopped working meaning the devenv.com command erroring out with very little information what provided in the question above.

After looking over the articles and deep-diving into the logs I found that there is a flag with devenv.com which suggest logging the error which is super useful.

```
devenv.com "PathToSsisSolution.sln" /rebuild "Development" /log c:\logfilepath.txt
```

With the above command, I was able to look at the logs and upon googling the solution for those logs I found that I have reset the visual studio settings and I set up this command just before my devenv.com command

`"%VS2017_Path%\devenv.com" /ResetSettings
"%VS2017_Path%\devenv.com" /setup`

And everything starts to working as normal.